# Dequeue the exception queue in ORACLE AQ

Tags: plsql, oracle-aq, advanced-queuing, enqueue

I am new to the Oracle AQ process and have a few questions about the exception queue. Here's my scenario:

Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0

Create Table and Queue:

```
BEGIN

  DBMS_AQADM.CREATE_QUEUE_TABLE (
      QUEUE_TABLE  =>'ADD_QUEUE_TABLE',
      MULTIPLE_CONSUMERS   => TRUE,
      QUEUE_PAYLOAD_TYPE   => 'ADD_OBJECT_TYPE');

  DBMS_AQADM.CREATE_QUEUE (
      QUEUE_NAME  => 'ADD_QUEUE',
      QUEUE_TABLE => 'ADD_QUEUE_TABLE',
      max_retries => 6,
      retry_delay => 1800);

  DBMS_AQADM.START_QUEUE (QUEUE_NAME => 'ADD_QUEUE');

END;    
/
```

To my understanding, it should retry dequeue for 6 times with delay of 30 mins and then send to exception queue. But in my case, it did send the messages to exception queue a lot before. I want your inputs to know if there is something I am missing or doing it wrong.

Enqueue:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TXN_ENQUEUE_PROCEDURE (HN_TXN_SEQ IN NUMBER)
AS
  ENQUEUE_OPTIONS      DBMS_AQ.ENQUEUE_OPTIONS_T;
  MESSAGE_PROPERTIES   DBMS_AQ.MESSAGE_PROPERTIES_T;
  MESSAGE_HANDLE       RAW (16);
  MESSAGE             TXN_OBJECT_TYPE;
BEGIN
  MESSAGE := TXN_OBJECT_TYPE (HN_TXN_SEQ);
  DBMS_AQ.ENQUEUE (QUEUE_NAME           => 'FILE_QUEUE',
                   ENQUEUE_OPTIONS      => ENQUEUE_OPTIONS,
                   MESSAGE_PROPERTIES   => MESSAGE_PROPERTIES,
                   PAYLOAD              => MESSAGE,
                   MSGID                => MESSAGE_HANDLE);
  COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Dequeue:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TXN_DEQUEUE_PROCEDURE (
  CONTEXT    RAW,
  REGINFO    SYS.AQ$_REG_INFO,
  DESCR      SYS.AQ$_DESCRIPTOR,
  PAYLOAD    RAW,
  PAYLOADL   NUMBER)
AS
  DEQUEUE_OPTIONS      DBMS_AQ.DEQUEUE_OPTIONS_T;
  MESSAGE_PROPERTIES   DBMS_AQ.MESSAGE_PROPERTIES_T;
  MESSAGE_HANDLE       RAW (16);
  MESSAGE              TXN_OBJECT_TYPE;
BEGIN
  DEQUEUE_OPTIONS.WAIT := DBMS_AQ.NO_WAIT;
  DEQUEUE_OPTIONS.CONSUMER_NAME := 'MYSUBSCRIBER';
  DEQUEUE_OPTIONS.NAVIGATION := DBMS_AQ.FIRST_MESSAGE;
  DEQUEUE_OPTIONS.MSGID := DESCR.MSG_ID;
  DEQUEUE_OPTIONS.CONSUMER_NAME := DESCR.CONSUMER_NAME;
  LOOP
    DBMS_AQ.DEQUEUE (QUEUE_NAME           => DESCR.QUEUE_NAME,
                     DEQUEUE_OPTIONS      => DEQUEUE_OPTIONS,
                     MESSAGE_PROPERTIES   => MESSAGE_PROPERTIES,
                     PAYLOAD              => MESSAGE,
                     MSGID                => MESSAGE_HANDLE);
    INSERT INTO MESSAGE_TABLE_SAMPLE  VALUES (MESSAGE.HN_TXN_SEQ);

    XYZ_PACKAGE.ABC_API (MESSAGE.HN_TXN_SEQ); ---- CALL API ----
    COMMIT;
  END LOOP;
END;    
/
```

When I execute enqueue and if applications goes down or for any other reasons, the messages goes to exception queue. And if I dequeue from the exception queue, do I need to mention ( XYZ_PACKAGE.ABC_API (MESSAGE.HN_TXN_SEQ); ---- CALL API ----) within the dequeue process or it will be automatically called like normal queue dequeue process.

Exception queue :

```
EXECUTE DBMS_AQADM.START_QUEUE('AQ$_FILE_QUEUE_TABLE_E', false, true);

DECLARE
  dequeue_options DBMS_AQ.dequeue_options_t;
  message_properties DBMS_AQ.message_properties_t;
  dq_msgid RAW(16);
  payload RAW(1);
  no_messages exception;
  pragma exception_init (no_messages, -25263);
  msg_count number(2);
  cursor c_msg_ids is
    select msg_id
    from aq$FILE_QUEUE_TABLE
    where queue = 'AQ$_FILE_QUEUE_TABLE_E';
BEGIN
  dequeue_options.consumer_name := null;
  dequeue_options.wait := DBMS_AQ.NO_WAIT;
  dequeue_options.navigation := DBMS_AQ.FIRST_MESSAGE;
  dequeue_options.dequeue_mode := dbms_aq.remove_nodata;
  For v_msg_id in c_msg_ids loop
    dequeue_options.msgid := v_msg_id.msg_id;
    msg_count := 0;
    DBMS_AQ.DEQUEUE(queue_name => 'sys.AQ$_FILE_QUEUE_TABLE_E',
                    dequeue_options => dequeue_options,
                    message_properties => message_properties,
                    payload => payload,
                    msgid => dq_msgid);
    dbms_output.put_line('Message id : '||v_msg_id.msg_id||' removed');
    msg_count := msg_count + 1;
    dequeue_options.msgid := null;
    dequeue_options.navigation := DBMS_AQ.NEXT_MESSAGE;
  END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN no_messages THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('No of Messages Removed: '||msg_count);
    COMMIT;
END;
/
```

After executing the above one, it removes the messages from the exception queue. Do I need to mention ( XYZ_PACKAGE.ABC_API (MESSAGE.HN_TXN_SEQ); ---- CALL API ----) anywhere in between?

Is it better to execute exception queue or to have max_retries and with retry_delay?

If the messages move to exception queue, and if I run a query to dequeue them. Do they follow the same mechanism as in dequeue the normal queue and execute any additional apis that uses the message as input?

Thank you!